# How to use Power BI REST API's in Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, api, active-directory, powerbi, azure-data-factory

I am trying to create a list  of all the workspaces  and the reports contained in each one of them for a documentation project.

I found online that we can use this to get the workspaces, I wanna use it with a "web" activity:

```
https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/groups
```

And then I want to use the IDs we get in the output with a foreach and another web activity inside of it and use this to get the reports in each workspace, then copy it somewhere (datalake or DB) :

```
https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/groups/{groupId}/reports
```

But I don't know how to configure the activity and the authentication.

If there is a better way like connecting directly to Power BI I'm all ears, I tried to do a get data from web source but I don't have any "key" for API and organization authentication doesn't work.

When I run the code here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/groups/getgroups it works perfectly.

Thanks in advance

Comment: The link you provided mentioned that before you call the api, required scopes are ' Workspace.Read.All or Workspace.ReadWrite.All', so have you add the scope in azure ad and then get an access token to use in request head when calling the api?

Comment: I registered an app with those permissions and I've created a secret for it. I don't know what to do after that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'But I don't know how to configure the activity and the authentication.' For this question, I'm not sure if you don't know how to use access token to call an API.

1. Register an azure ad application with the api permission of 'https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api/Workspace.ReadWrite.All'
   so that you can generate an access token by this application with
   this scope. [Add api permission](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embedded/register-app?tabs=customers%2CAzure#change-your-azure-ad-apps-permissions).
2. Use [ropc flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth-ropc) to generate an access token. This flow contains user information so that your api could know who you are to return correct groups.
3. Add 'Authorization' in request head with value of 'Bearer accessToken' to call the api.

[image]
[image]

ropc flow 1.0:

[image]

Comment: If I misunderstand your problem, pls point it out,thanks

Comment: my problem is that I don't know how to get that token that you've used after "Bearer". Since it is refreshed every hour I don't know how to get it automatically without going to Microsoft's platform and execute the http

Comment: The token is used to call api, it stands for the authenticaion key, and we need use authentication flows from azure ad to generate the token. [Ropc flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth-ropc) is one of the flows. Follow the tutorial, we need to register azure add app, add api permission, create client secret and call the login request. And you said that u don't know how to get it automatically, do u mean that you require a sample or you have no ideas on how to keep the token effective all the time? Or any others?

Comment: I'm kinda new to this so I'm gonna tell you exactly what I did.
1. I have registered an app here: http://dev.powerbi.com/Apps (I gave all the read permissions)
2. The Azure Admin made me App Owner
3. I added from the portal the Tenant.Read.All permission
4. I added a Client Secret
5. Now from Postman I want to generate a refreshable token, so I do this:

POST  https://login.microsoftonline.com/"TenantID"/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id=Client ID
scope: user.read openid profile offline_access
client_secret=secret value
username= My email
password= My password
grant_type=password

Comment: @adnane Yes, let's start. I focused on the point of calling api ' h t tps:/ /api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/groups'. This api needs a token in request head as you seen in my screenshot, and via the token, api can know who are calling it and if he has the permission in this api. So next question is how to generate the token and here we need to use azure ad authentication flow which is provided to generate access token. I'll post a doc on one of the flows which uses userid and possword to generate token in my answer.

Comment: I received the following error :     "error": "invalid_grant",
    "error_description": "AADSTS50126: Error validating credentials due to invalid username or password.  I am sure that I put in the correct email and password

Comment: @adnane that's strange, and how have you tried to use tools like postman or the one in my screenshot to try to generate the token? I tried in my side and the error you met only appears when I used wrong password.

Comment: Here : https://ibb.co/0q083CT   I found this online and it got me a token but I don't know if that's useful : https://ibb.co/yQ9qpdN

Comment: @adnane the flow you used in the second screenshot in credential flow and version is v1.0(differ from the one I posted in the answer) and it can also achieve the same target. But what I tried in my place used ropc flow and it worked too. I think it's also suitable for you.

Comment: I did exactly the same as you and it didn't work :(   thank you anyway I will still put you as best answer because that's what everyone told me to do but for some reason it didn't work for me

Comment: I tried credential flow and it didn't work, I think it may result from 'myorg' in the api url, it requires a clear target so need to use account and pwd. And the first screenshot showed that your domain is xx.onmicrosoft.com but userid is not, and you mentioned that u added the email as the account. I think you can check if the account exists in the tenant where you registered the app. That's pretty puzzled. Anyway, thanks very much for your mark.